# Why this simple code causes extra slow PROC_DLATCH pass

Tags: yosys

I use (excellent) Yosys to synthetize (read_verilog & proc) the code below (gray incrementer logic for async fifo) to make some formal checks and found that it is incredibly slow.

For `W=2` it synthetizes in `0.2sec`, `W=3` in `230sec`. It didn't end for `W=4` yet and I need `W=5` for my design.

Yosys is version `0.9+932`.
The **mem2reg** attr is used because I wanted it as regs not mem (smtbmc doesn't like nonconst meminit).

I'm wondering if it is by design or there is some bug/inefficiency in PROC_DLATCH ?

```
module gray5_inc #(parameter K=1,W=3) (
        input [W-1:0] in,
        output [W-1:0] out);
        localparam SZ=1<<W;

        function [W-1:0] gray; 
                input [W-1:0] x;
                begin
                        gray = x^{1'b0,x[W-1:1]};
                end
        endfunction

        integer i;
        (* mem2reg *)
        reg [W-1:0] rom [SZ-1:0];
        initial begin
                for(i=0;i<SZ;i=i+1) rom[gray(i)] = gray(i+K);
        end
        assign out = rom[in];
endmodule
```